# Remove a dictinoary if empty list is found in Python

Tags: python, json-normalize

I have a list of dictionaries present. Below is my sample data:

```
[
  {
    "Customer_id": "123",
    "Account_no": "123456789012",
    "Amount": 3000,
    "Transaction": [
      {
        "date": "20/06/25",
        "time": "12:19:39",
        "Shop": "Amazon",
        "Comments": "Valuable items"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Customer_id": "123",
    "Account_no": "123456789012",
    "Amount": 3000,
    "Transaction": []
  }
]
```

Here I need to remove the dictionary if I find the Transaction list  is empty.Below is the code I tried:

```
 res=list(filter(None,({key:val for key,val in sub.items() if val} for sub in results)))
 #results is the list of dictionary
```

My Output:

```
[
  {
    "Customer_id": "123",
    "Account_no": "123456789012",
    "Amount": 3000,
    "Transaction": [
      {
        "date": "20/06/25",
        "time": "12:19:39",
        "Shop": "Amazon",
        "Comments": "Valuable items"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Customer_id": "123",
    "Account_no": "123456789012",
    "Amount": 3000,
  }
]
```

I am able to remove that particular list only not the details associated with that.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "Customer_id": "123",
    "Account_no": "123456789012",
    "Amount": 3000,
    "Transaction": [
      {
        "date": "20/06/25",
        "time": "12:19:39",
        "Shop": "Amazon",
        "Comments": "Valuable items"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please let me know how to do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use list comprehension, ```[v for v in results if v.get('Transaction')]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following list comprehension

```
res = [sub for sub in results if sub['Transaction']]
```

Result

```
[
    {
       'Customer_id': '123', 
       'Amount': 3000, 
       'Account_no': 
       '123456789012', 
       'Transaction': 
           [
               {
                   'Comments': 'Valuable items', 
                   'time': '12:19:39', 
                   'date': '20/06/25', 
                   'Shop': 'Amazon'
               }
          ]
     }
]
```

Comment: What if ``Transaction`` key does not exists ?

Answer (score 1):

- It's not clear what the end goal for the data is, but using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is an option if you also want to do any analysis.
- Specifically, use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), which is great for reading in lists of JSON (dict) data

  - When `Transaction` is an empty list, the set of data will be ignored during parsing
- Given the following example using your sample `JSON` assigned to `data`
- Notice the dataframe does not include the data, where `Transaction` was empty
- Now the data can be analyzed.
- This answer assumes, based on the example data, that the `Transaction` key will always be present.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'Transaction', ['Customer_id', 'Account_no', 'Amount'])

# display(df)
       date      time    Shop        Comments Customer_id    Account_no Amount
0  20/06/25  12:19:39  Amazon  Valuable items         123  123456789012   3000
```

Comment: Thanks Trenton! Yes I can also use pandas for this .Thanks for your solution